# Why would gasoline engine exhaust smell like perfume?

Tags: exhaust, smell

Quite often I encounter a vehicle that has exhaust with rather sharp smell similar to perfume. As far as I know this is attributed to the engine malfunctioning - normally working engine will exhaust gases without sharp smells.

What exactly causes the gasoline engine to produce exhaust with sharp perfume-like smell?

Comment: I have to admit that I read your question wrong at first.  It read in my head as a proposal for a new perfume for ladies that would like to attract the attention of a motorhead.  "Is that Eau de Racetrack?"  ;-)

Comment: Wasn't it Harley-Davidson that did that one @Bob? :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most of the perfumes I know have a lot of carbon content (Alcohol based). So if I am to take a quick guess, this might be unburnt fuel being pumped out in gaseous form, a precursor to blackening of your tail pipes.

Or your vehicle might just be wooing the beetle behind - who knows? :)

Answer (score 4):

If it's a sweet smell it might be antifreeze, although you'd usually get white smoke as well.

Comment: Emm.. How would antifreeze get into exhaust I wonder?

Comment: From memory, I believe a leaking head gasket would allow coolant into the combustion chamber which would then make its way into the exhaust.

Answer (score 0):

It's likely due to incomplete combustion, and the fact that synthetic perfumes are made from petrochemicals and have many components in common with gasoline, hence the sharp perfume-like odor. 
It's also a good reason not to overdo it with perfumes and fragrances - they really aren't good for anyone, especially not when inhaling them 24/7.